# Op type not registered 'cond_true_5' in binary running on DESKTOP

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have saved the model by disabling eager execution in tf2.6 version. Below is the snippet used for saving and running

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), batch_size=None)
x1=tf.keras.Input(1, dtype=tf.int32)
print(type(x1), type(x)) #<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
y = tf.cond(tf.less(x1,5), lambda :tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x), lambda :tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x))
model=tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[x,x1], outputs=[y])
model.save("cond.h5")
model.summary()
```

**Running**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()


model=load_model('cond.h5')
x = np.ones((1, 224,224,3), dtype=np.float32)
x1 = np.zeros((1, 1), dtype=np.int32)
z=model.predict([x,x1], batch_size=1)
```

Error:

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Op type not registered 'cond_true_5' in binary running on anilm. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed. while building NodeDef 'tf_op_layer_cond/cond/then/_0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `tf.cond` operation is causing a problem because it is not a `Keras` layer. You could try wrapping the operation in a `Lambda` layer:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), batch_size=None)
x1 = tf.keras.Input(1, dtype=tf.int32)
y = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.cond(tf.less(x[0], 5), lambda: tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x[1]), lambda: tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x[1])))([x1, x])
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[x, x1], outputs=[y])
model.save("cond.h5")
model.summary()
```

I would still recommend a custom layer though.